# How do companies like facebook send notification emails to users?

Tags: mass-emails

How do companies like facebook send notification emails to users? Is it part of the code for their site or do they use a third-party email marketing company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook hosts their email delivery services internally.  Therefore, it's part of the code for their own services.

Other companies have chosen other solutions, including the use of email services, or their own.